# Set checkbox value from database in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have 8 `checkboxes`.
 
On the `page load` event I want to write the code such that
if the `value` in the `database` is `"Submitted"` the `checkbox` will appear `checked`.
If the `value` is `"Not Submitted"` it will appear `unchecked`.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Show us what you've tried already..

Comment: check the posted answer or show us your code what you had tried?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can have something like this

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
     var isChecked = dbvalue.ToLower() == "submitted" ? true : false;
     for (var i = 0; i < 8;i++ )
     {
         CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)Form.FindControl("chk" + i);
         if(chk != null) chk.checked = isChecked;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check the values like this

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    if(dbvalue=="Submitted")
    {
      chk1.checked=true;
      chk2.checked=true;
      chk3.checked=true;
      chk4.checked=true;
      chk5.checked=true;
      chk6.checked=true;
      chk7.checked=true;
      chk8.checked=true;
    }
    else if(dbvalue=="Not Submitted")
    {
        chk1.checked=false;
      chk2.checked=false;
      chk3.checked=false;
      chk4.checked=false;
      chk5.checked=false;
      chk6.checked=false;
      chk7.checked=false;
      chk8.checked=false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If don't want to do anything in the code-behind, a faster and easy method would be to create a new column of data type bit on the select query  and then just bind the checkbox to that. 0 = false and 1 = true. Example would be:

```
SELECT
CAST((CASE WHEN SubmitColumn = 'Submitted' THEN
    1
ELSE
    0
END) AS BIT) AS chkValue

FROM Table_1
```